# how to get oracle port no from sql query

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Is it possible to get the oracle server port no from a sql query?

Thanks,
Fell

Comment: I believe you're looking for the Listener port number, which is a separate process from the database itself.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be directly possible: see the discussion here
[on askTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1615437921675)

Answer (score 0):

No, but in order to run a query you're going to need a connection to the DB so I suspect you can get the port using a call to `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.getURL()`.  Not sure exactly what the Oracle drivers return but something like this should do the trick:

```
String url = connection.getMetadata().getURL();
String port = url.substring(url.indexOf(":"), url.indexof("/", url.indexOf(":")) - 1);
```

Comment: chicken and egg: how can you make a connection without knowing the port number?  can't get meta data without it.

Comment: @duffymo: like I said, if you're going to run a query you must have a connection.  If the question was how do I connect to some Oracle instance on the network somewhere then then agreed you're screwed and it's time to phone the DBAs and get some more information.

Comment: im creating a connection to the oracle database using the sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc driver.Just require the DSN to create the connection.Once I have the connection I want to find out the port no on which the server is running..

Comment: @Fell: I've managed to avoid the JDBC bridge driver but surely it still needs the connection information host, *port*, SID, etc, which is returned as per the docs (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html)?  If the port is missing then I suspect the DB is listening on the default port, 1521 I think for Oracle.